# jQuery in MVC View is not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've been searching for this answer for a while without any luck, so I thought I'd post the question.

I'm certain I can code around this, but I'd really like to understand why this isn't working.

I've got this tiny bit of jQuery code:

```
$("body").on("change", "#StackNameId190", function () {
    alert('got it');
});
```

If I include this code in my .js file, it works fine.  However, if I include it in the view that is accessing it - it doesn't.

I have similar body/change script in views and they work fine, but this one doesn't.  The reason I need it in the view is that I want to be able to dynamically generate the script based on the content in the model.  The end result would look something like this:

```
@foreach (var stack in @Model.Stacks)
    {
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("$('body').on('change', '#StackNameId{0}', function () {{$('#btnStackName{0}').click(); alert('got it');}});", @stack.Id));
    }
```

What I don't understand is, why does this work fine in the .js file, but not in the view?  The only thing I can see that might be affecting it is that the text box with the Id of StackNameId190 is being generated from a partial view.  I'm not sure if or why that would have any affect though.   Here is the code that is trying to access the jQuery:

```
<div id="submitStackName@(Model.Id)">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_SubmitStackName", "Position",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = String.Format("submitStackName{0}",@Model.Id),
            OnFailure = "ajaxFailureHandler",
            OnComplete = String.Format("updatedStackName('#{0}')", String.Format("submitStackName{0}", @Model.Id))
        }, new { @id = String.Format("StackNameForm{0}", @Model.Id) }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "width:150px" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { style = "width:300px", @id = String.Format("StackNameId{0}", @Model.Id) })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        <button type="submit" id="btnStackName@(Model.Id)" style="display:none"></button>
    }
</div>
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what about delegating event to document instead of body? But as i see it, you'd have better to use class instead of IDs

Comment: You are wrapping this jQuery with dom ready aren't you?

Comment: You may want to show the full CSHTML or at least specify the order.  Are you possibly generating that script BEFORE importing your jquery script?

Comment: The full code is difficult to provide because it's large. The initial code snippet is from the <script> portion of the code at the top of the primary view (.cshtml) file.  The second bit of script only exists as a comment right now.  The third bit of script comes from partial view that is rendered within the main CSHTML file - but it's several partial views deep.

Comment: Also, I'm very new to jQuery/javascript coding, so I might have this wrong, but my understanding is that document ready function is shortcut by using $("body").  The short cut by default is that it's run when the document is ready.  That being said, I tested the same code with the jQuery being wrapped in a document.ready() method and it had the same result.

Comment: Why would it be better to use class instead of ids?  In this case, the code inside the jQuery is simplistic, just showing an alert, but the real code will be issuing a button-click which will also have a specific id.  This is hard to read, but shown in the @foreach piece of code in snippet #2.

Comment: Problem Solved ... but I'm not sure why it's solved. I moved the scripts render from the bottom of my _layout.cshtml file to the top of the file, just below the body tag.

Comment: jQuery was probably being added after this code snippet - if the snippet was just in the view body then that would almost certainly be the case. If it was in a section it would depend where that section is rendered in your layout file. The console is your friend for debugging this sort of problem - you'd probably see something like "jQuery is undefined" or "$ is undefined". The js you included the snippet in file was probably added *after* the jQuery script so jQuery was then available and ready to use.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  I'll have to spend some time learning how to use the console as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved ... but I'm not sure why it's solved. I moved the scripts render from the bottom of my _layout.cshtml file to the top of the file, just below the body tag.

I'm still not 100% certain why this is now working, but it seems as though jQuery wasn't ready yet.